# Axis Error - Fault - Failed to determine deployed service names.; nested exception

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error while trying to access my deployed webservice in my `tomcat7` server. Here's my error:

AXIS error

> Sorry, something seems to have gone wrong... here are the details:
>
> Fault - Failed to determine deployed service names.; nested exception
>   is:   org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: Could not find class for
>   the service named: org.ulf.service.operation.VolunteerService Hint:
>   you may need to copy your class files/tree into the right location
>   (which depends on the servlet system you are using).; nested exception
>   is:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.ulf.service.operation.VolunteerService AxisFault  faultCode:
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.generalException 
>   faultSubcode:   faultString: Could not find class for the service
>   named: org.ulf.service.operation.VolunteerService Hint: you may need
>   to copy your class files/tree into the right location (which depends
>   on the servlet system you are using).; nested exception is: 
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.ulf.service.operation.VolunteerService  faultActor:   faultNode:
>   faultDetail:      {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:127.0.0.1
>
> Could not find class for the service named:
>   org.ulf.service.operation.VolunteerService Hint: you may need to copy
>   your class files/tree into the right location (which depends on the
>   servlet system you are using).; nested exception is: 
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.ulf.service.operation.VolunteerService    at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getServiceClass(JavaProvider.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.initServiceDesc(JavaProvider.java:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.getInitializedServiceDesc(SOAPService.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.makeNewInstance(WSDDService.java:500)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getDeployedServices(WSDDDeployment.java:503)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getDeployedServices(FileProvider.java:296)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler.getDeployedServiceNames(QSWSDLHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler.updateSoapAddressLocationURLs(QSWSDLHandler.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler.invoke(QSWSDLHandler.java:72)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.processQuery(AxisServlet.java:1226)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:249)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731).....

BTW - my server is in the cloud.
Hope you can help me with this. Thanks.